# Flutter app is not rendering widget properly in release mode

Tags: flutter, widget

I am running the project in debug mode and all widgets are rendering properly. However, in release mode the widgets are not rendering properly. The widget sometimes render and sometimes do not render at all.

Unfortunately, all the code cannot be put here for issue replication. So, I am providing only the main method in here. The repo can be accessed as below.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/ExpertKiD/flutter_widget_not_rendering_app.git
```

Flutter Issue: [#126820](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126820)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/view_model/auth_view_model/auth_view_model.dart';
import '/view_model/auth_view_model/login_success_view_model.dart';
import '/constants/theme_constant.dart';
import 'constants/routes_constant.dart';
import 'core/injections/injections.dart';

import 'services/shared_preference_service/access_token_service.dart';
import 'services/shared_preference_service/forgot_password_token_service.dart';

void main() async {
  // GetIt configuration

  // await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await configureDependencies();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AccessTokenServiceProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => LoginSuccessViewModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ForgotPasswordTokenService()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        darkTheme: appThemeData(),
        theme: appThemeData(),
        themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
        initialRoute: Routes.splashRoute,
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.getRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot answer the question without knowing what widget is causing the problem. Can you please provide more details?